# How to change global options with Rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

To solve the issue "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" in **R**, you need to change global options as follows:

```
 options(java.parameters = c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m"))
```

What if I use **rpy2** in **python**.
I tried each of the following commands

```
from rpy2.robjects import *
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rbase=importr('base')
from rpy2.robjects.functions import SignatureTranslatedFunction


rbase.options = SignatureTranslatedFunction(rbase.options,
                                             init_prm_translate={'java_parameters': rbase.c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m")})

rbase.options(java_parameters = StrVector(rbase.c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m")))

rbase.options(java_parameters = rbase.c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m"))
```

But they have no effect.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lgautier, my problem was solved by adding `setenv _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Xmx2g"` to ~/.cshrc.

Answer (score 0):

The following might not be doing when you intend to achieve:

```
rbase.options = SignatureTranslatedFunction(
    rbase.options,
    init_prm_translate={
        'java_parameters': rbase.c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m")
    }
)
```

The named argument `init_prm_translate` can be used to optionally rename
parameter name, and the main reason for this is that in R names like `foo.bar` are syntactically valid, but they are are not Python. There is a default simple name translation rule that replaces `.` with `_` but R can have functions with both `foo.bar` and `foo_bar` parameters, in which case a manual naming rule might be convenient.

For example:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

f = ro.r('function(x=1, y=2) {x}')
f(x=3)  # returns [3]

# translate the named parameter 'x' to 'foo'
f_t = ro.functions.SignatureTranslatedFunction(
    f, init_prm_translate={'foo': 'x'}
)
f_t(foo=3)  # returns [3]
```